# Is it possible to find more than one eigenvector for a given eigenvalue because of free variables?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let's say I have a matrix \begin{bmatrix}7&3\\3&-1\end{bmatrix}

I get the corresponding eigenvalues $8$ and $-2$. Without showing all the work, if I plug in $-2$, I eventually get to one reduced equation:
$$
\begin{cases} 3x + y = 0  \\ 3x = -y \end{cases}
$$
In this situation, $x$ is a  basic variable, but I can make so many different numbers $y$ and get a ton of different results. Is that ok? For example, I could get $(-3, 1)$, but I also could get $(1, -3)$.

Comment: Typically you have all scalar multiples of one eigenvector as eigenvectors. The so-called _eigenspace_ corresponding to an eigenvalue is at least one dimensional (ie all eigenvectors for a given eigenvalue are scalar multiples), but it could be a higher dimension too.

Comment: If you want to find eigenvectors of a matrix, you typically want your eigenvectors to be linear independent. With that in mind you can now answer the question how many eigenvectors you ought to find for your matrix

Comment: Are you sure $(-3,1)$ satisfies this system?

Answer (score 1):

By plugging $-2$, we get to
$$3x+y=0$$
Writing it out as a vector:
$$\vec{v} = \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} x \\ -3x \end{bmatrix} = x \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -3 \end{bmatrix}$$

Hence, all multiples of the vector $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -3 \end{bmatrix}$$ Are solutions to the equation. We say, then, that this vector forms the *eigenspace* of this eigenvalue.

So answering your question: **Yes, that is ok**. Every multiple of the vector will also be an eigenvector *with the same eigenvalue*.

Also notice that, in your case, neither $(-3,1)$ nor $(1,-3)$ are solutions to the system and hence are not eigenvectors with eigenvalue $2$.